# jQuery - trigger an ajax update when no keypress is detected for a while?

Tags: jquery

Very quick question - I'm writing a basic script which updates a table based on what's in a textarea. Once this has been updated, I display a little jGrowl message informing the user that the information has indeed been updated.

But I'm wondering, what if they're on the page, and don't click off that textarea (so onchange doesn't trigger, nor does blur etc etc) before they close the page? Is there anyway of triggering this event purely when there's a delay in typing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this below

```
//setup before functions
    var timer1;                //timer identifier
    var waitTime = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

    //on keyup, start the countdown
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        timer1 = setTimeout(doneTyping, waitTime);
    });

    //on keydown, clear the countdown 
    $('input').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer1);
    });

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Wow! This is perfect, thank you so much - one thing though, it seems to repeat itself after triggering, but I guess I could fix that by maybe setting a flag of some kind? Thanks again

Comment: No problem, will prob need some tweeks to fit your requirement :)if it solves your problem dont forget to mark it as accepted answer

Comment: Thanks, I'm certain it'll be the accepted answer, I'm just trying to figure this out. I've tried putting a little condition to see if timer1 is set, but then it'll only update once. Hmm!

Comment: Okay, wow that is fantastic, thank you! I'm ever so sorry to be a pain though, but I've just realised I need to pass in the ID so the ajax knows which of the notes to work with, but unfortunately this just triggers instantly since I've done this? http://pastebin.com/yeGUbBnn

Comment: Ok last prob best ot ask a new question if you need something else, but you need to define functions in a timeout like this http://jsfiddle.net/WyMFJ/3/

Comment: This is actually perfect, once again thank you so so much! Really, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout() after the keypress to setup a timer to trigger a function that handles your ajax call. When the key is pressed again just clear the timer and reset it, and kill it all together once the field has lost focus. Hope this helps!

Comment: Or just look at what Dominic Green posted!